# Why do I need to set the "runtimes" for tests library in .NET Core?

Tags: mstest, .net-core, project.json

I created a VS 2015 U3 solution that contains a netstandard1.3 PCL library `X` and a netcoreapp1.0 test library `Y`. I'm using MSTest (dotnet-test-mstest and MSTest.TestFramework).

This is `src\X\project.json`:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {}
  }
}
```

This is `test\Y\project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "testRunner": "mstest",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0",
    "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview",
    "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.0-preview",
    "X": {      "target": "project"    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win8-x64": {}
  }
}
```

It turned out that I need to have this last

```
"runtimes": {
    "win8-x64": {}
}
```

in `Y\project.json`, otherwise I get the following error:

*_dotnet-test Error: 0 : System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'._*

Why is that? Can't I have a generic test app that will work everywhere if I install the SDK?

Comment: Could you show your whole project.json?

Comment: I wonder if you are on an older/intermediate dotnet CLI installer. Kindly check.